# Setting Timeout as Activity indicator keeps spinning when there is no response from webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, xcode6, connection-timeout

I am using REST API to fetch data. I have two methods, one for ResponceSucces and other for responceFailure. In responce failure I simply dismiss the activity indicator. Sometimes it happens that data is not retrieved but still activity indicator keeps spinning infinitely. And ResponceFailure method is not Called.

My question is can I set timeout interval to my web service, to check if response did not come, then activity indicator must be dismissed after some time for example 20/30 seconds.
Below is my code:

```
-(void)messagesGetSuccess:(FBListingsWebHandler*)handler response:(NSDictionary*)response
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages removeAllObjects];
    NSArray *messagesArray = [response objectForKey:@"message"];
    if([[FBUserManager sharedUserManager] userType] == kUserShipper){
        //extract usernames of transporters who placed bid on selected listing
        NSArray *userNames;
        NSMutableArray *transporterNames;
        NSDictionary *biddingsDic = [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager] getModelDictionary:kModelBiddings];
        if ([biddingsDic count] > 0){
            userNames = [[biddingsDic allValues] valueForKey:@"userName"];
            NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:userNames];
            NSSet *uniqueNames = [orderedSet set];
            transporterNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueNames allObjects]];
        }
        //add transporter records in messages dictionary who have messages for selected listing
        for (int i = 1; i < [messagesArray count]; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSDictionary *groupedMsgDic = [messagesArray objectAtIndex:i];
            int count = (int)[[[groupedMsgDic allValues] objectAtIndex:0] count];
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                FBMessagesModel *model = [[FBMessagesModel alloc] initWithMessageItems:[[[groupedMsgDic allValues] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:j]];
                [modelArray addObject:model];
                model = nil;
            }
            [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages setObject:modelArray forKey:[[groupedMsgDic allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
            //remove transporter usernames from array who have messages besides bid for selected listing
            if([transporterNames containsObject:[[groupedMsgDic allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]]){
                [transporterNames removeObject:[[groupedMsgDic allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
            modelArray = nil;
        }
        //add transporter records in messages dictionary who placed bid but have no message for selected listing
        for (int i = 0; i < [transporterNames count]; i++) {
            NSString *path = [[[biddingsDic allValues] objectAtIndex:[userNames indexOfObject:[transporterNames objectAtIndex:i]]] photoPath];
            int transporterId = [[[biddingsDic allValues] objectAtIndex:[userNames indexOfObject:[transporterNames objectAtIndex:i]]] userId];
            NSString *objectForZeroMsgs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d",path,transporterId];
            [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages setObject:objectForZeroMsgs forKey:[transporterNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        transporterNames = nil;

        //        [self tableView:self.shipperGroupedMessagesTableView_ numberOfRowsInSection:0];
        [self.shipperGroupedMessagesTableView_ reloadData];
    }else if([[FBUserManager sharedUserManager] userType] == kUserTransporter){
        for (int i = 1; i < [messagesArray count]; i++) {
            FBMessagesModel *model = [[FBMessagesModel alloc] initWithMessageItems:[messagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages setObject:model forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",model.mailId]];
            if(model.mailMessage && ![model.mailMessage isEqualToString:@""]){
                [self createMessageBubble:model];
            }
            model = nil;
        }
        [self.bubbleTableView_ reloadData];
    }

}
-(void)messagesGetFailure:(FBListingsWebHandler*)handler
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages removeAllObjects];
    if([[FBUserManager sharedUserManager] userType] == kUserTransporter){
        [self.bubbleTableView_ reloadData];
    }
    else if([[FBUserManager sharedUserManager] userType] == kUserShipper){
        if([[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages count] == 0){
            NSDictionary *biddingsDic = [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager] getModelDictionary:kModelBiddings];
            if ([biddingsDic count] > 0){
                NSArray *userNames = [[biddingsDic allValues] valueForKey:@"userName"];
                NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:userNames];
                NSSet *uniqueNames = [orderedSet set];
                NSArray *transporterNames = [uniqueNames allObjects];
                [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages removeAllObjects];
                for (int i = 0; i < [transporterNames count]; i++) {
                    NSString *path = [[[biddingsDic allValues] objectAtIndex:[userNames indexOfObject:[transporterNames objectAtIndex:i]]] photoPath];
                    int transporterId = [[[biddingsDic allValues] objectAtIndex:[userNames indexOfObject:[transporterNames objectAtIndex:i]]] userId];
                    NSString *objectForZeroMsgs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d",path,transporterId];
                    [[FBModelManager sharedModelManager].messages setObject:objectForZeroMsgs forKey:[transporterNames objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
                [self.shipperGroupedMessagesTableView_ reloadData];
            }else{
                [self addNoMessagesLabel];
            }
        }
        [self.shipperGroupedMessagesTableView_ reloadData];
    }

}
```

I am adding a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Are you using any communications library ? For example AFNetworking allows to setup timeout. Can you post your connection method code?

Comment: @Christian my project is a very complex project.its not about one or  two web service calls.i can not use library

Comment: I'm working on an app that uses a synchro mecchanism every 10 seconds and user refresh on demand data. AFNetworking is a light layer over Apple framework. Anyway NSURLSession has timeout settings for request and resource via NSURLSessionConfiguration